# Issue with relam.io join tables, not loading links

Tags: android, realm

I've got the following tables mapped out, kept simple here...

```
Product
{
   String Id;
   String Name;
}

Form
{
   String Id;
   String Firstname;
   String Surname;
   Journey Journey;
   RealmList<FormProduct> Products;
}

Journey
{
   String Id;
   String Name;
}

FormProduct
{
   String Id;
   Product Product;
   Form Form;
   int Quantity;
}
```

As you can see FormProduct is a join table between Form and Product. The problem I'm having is that when I retrieve the form from the realm, it doesn't populate Products for me, the Journey link does work fine but this is a simple join. I know the FormProducts are definitely saving because if I do a query such as

`RealmResults<FormProducts> formProducts = realm.where(FormProducts.class).equalTo("Form.Id", formId[0]).findAll();`

it brings back the data I'm expecting. Is this the only way of retrieving FormProducts or should the link autoload (lazyload?) them for me?

I'm using version 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'. Must say that I'm really liking realm, it's way easier and faster than any of the ORMs I've tried. This is the only snag I've come across so far and it's probably something I'm doing wrong!

### Edit

Code to save form products

```
Form realmForm = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(params[0]);

for (Product rp : realmProducts) {

FormProducts formProducts = new FormProducts();
formProducts.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
formProducts.setForm(realmForm);
formProducts.setProduct(rp);                   
}

realm.copyToRealm(formProducts);
}
```

code to retrieve form

```
Form form = realm.where(Form.class).equalTo("Id", formId).findFirst();
```

The above code doesn't auto retrieve the Products. I have to manually call

```
RealmResults<FormProducts> formProducts = realm.where(FormProducts.class).equalTo("Form.Id", formId).findAll();
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you try to retrieve the Products list, and the code where you save the Form Object

Comment: In Realm, you don't do joins. Instead you can use relationships between classes: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#relationships

Comment: I do have relationships defined as you can see by my form and formproduct entities. An I missing something?